# Subclassing with Delegates and IBActions

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, interface-builder

Let's assume I have the following class `GenericMoviePlayer` which has the following Outlets:

- PlayButton
- PauseButton
- DoneButton

Those `IBOutlet`s have their corresponding `IBActions`:

```
- (void) playTouched:(id)sender;
- (void) pauseTouched:(id)sender;
- (void) doneTouched:(id)sender;
```

When those buttons are touched a delegate of my class is informed.

Now this is all well but imagine I now want a special type of player which should inherit from this more generic player. I will now have new Outlets, new Actions and new methods in the delegate protocol. So how can I achieve this?

Subclassing and IBOutlets go well together but I don't know how I have to design my subclass that I can "inherit" the IBActions and kind-of overwrite the delegate protocol too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the `IBAction`s are defined in your `GenericMoviePlayer` header, those methods will be available to you in your `SpecificMoviePlayer` xib. So when you go to connect those buttons in your xib, those `GenericMoviePlayer` `IBAction`s will be available to you. Technically, if your `SpecificMoviePlayer` needs to add functionality to your play/pause/done methods (or change that functionality completely) you an override those methods.

This is kind of a high level overview, but if you have specific examples of what you want to accomplish, I'd be happy to help you out. I think your question needs a bit more clarification on exactly what you're hoping to accomplish (other than the reuse of code).

Comment: Thanks, have you any ideas on how to add functionality to the delegate object?

Comment: Are you trying to add functionality (for example) to your playTouched method? If so, you just have to include a new playTouched method in your SpecificMoviePlayer class and if you still need the functionality in your GenericMoviePlayer class to be called, use the super call. If you need a code sample of that, please let me know and I'll add one to my answer.